# Storing and Using JWT & Secret Key

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I have a login route for my app. I use `jwt tokens` to protect routes, but I have trouble to understand fully usage of `secret key`.

I tought I need to use secret key to verify `jwt`. Whenever user logs in, I send `JWT Token` and `Secret key` to user. `JWT` is stored in local storage (phone or app storage)

What should I about secret key? Should I both store to local and database?

**Login Route**

```
api.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {

var secretKey;

require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
    secretKey = buffer.toString('hex');

    //Create JWT and Secret Key
    jwt.sign({user}, secretKey, {expiresIn: '30s'}, (err, token) => {
        res.json({
            access_token : token,
            secret_key : secretKey

        });
    });


});
```

});

**Response After Login**

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImV4YW1wbGV1c2VyIiwiZW1haWwiOiJleGFtcGxlQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1NTExMTE1ODAsImV4cCI6MTU1MTExMTYxMH0.aSTVC-HcEdrH1KBNtuD_MoLZ8DWnSiM6bCqO4EgJ5zM",
"secret_key": "2e6a98abb5b23339ad14601d3bedc1d23847498cb18daf8cfc98c2a2095ec8f47d80053f6d4e22b8f6419407ac3083dc"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your secret key should never be given to anyone else. You need to keep this key a secret.  You can use the secret key to sign and issue tokens.  It can also be used to validate tokens, but using your secret key to validate tokens is generally a bad idea because you then need to send the secret key to the service that is validating the token, which goes against the advice in my first two sentences.

If your secret key is asymmetrically signed, you can generate a public key based on the secret (private) key in the form of what's called a JSON Web Key ([read about JWKs here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)).  That public key can then be given to anyone in the universe and the public key can be used to verify the JWT only; the public key cannot be used to sign new tokens.

This means that you should only store the secret key in one location and that should be on your auth server that signs and issues tokens.  Read more about asymmetric key signing [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment, appreciated and I learnt new things. I also would like to ask an issue about tokens. I can use tokens to protect API calls etc. Let's say I logged in to Instagram and when I go to Profile > Change Profile Picture or username etc, Instagram doesn't ask me the password or something to verify 'It's me to making changes'. How can I verify user for this kind of situations with tokens? When changing password I can get old password and verify in DB, but I don't have that option in this, what would you suggest me about logical or keywords to search on it?

Comment: When you are logged into Instagram or any service for that uses JWTs as its authentication method, the service doesn't need to ask you for the password to verify it is you..that is the purpose of sending the JWT along in your request.  The purpose of the JWT is to verify that you are who you say you are...if the token is tampered with, expired, etc. then Instagram will not believe that you are who you say you are, and in this case, deny your request to make changes.  As long as the token is changed, altered with, expired, and the signature it is signed isnt faulty, then your identity is valid

Comment: As far as I understand, when user logged in; I will create secret and jwt. I will send jwt to user, but keep secret or sign/verify key in DB. I don't need absolute protect to GET routes, but whenever user makes change importante profile picture, nickname, I will compare jwt with secret in DB. Am I right for this?

Comment: That could work although I would not recommend that strategy

Answer (score 4):

You should never send back to the client the secret key. You have to store the secret key in your server. You need it to sign and to verify jwt tokens.

This should be the flow:

- User login
- Server generates JWT (using the secret key) and send it (the jwt only) to the client
- The client saves the JWT in the local storage or where you want, and send it as an header to the server when he needs to do authenticated http calls.
- When the server recieves an authenticated call, he have to verify the JWT (using the same secret used for signin) to authenticate the call.

Read more about JWT at https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thanks for answer.

1- I need to create a secret key for per user and save it to user's DB, am I right about this?

2- With flow you mentioned, I need to query my DB to verify jwt in every api calls, but one of the most known benefit of jwt is verifying without DB check?

Comment: You can use the same secret key for all of your jwt tokens. You are right about the "no DB query benefit". In fact you should store your secret key as an enviorment variable. You could also store it in a database but you should query it just the first time you bootstrap the server,  leaving then the secret key in RAM.

Comment: As Chappie Johnson said, you could also use asymmetric keys. This will require more effort but revoking jwt will result easier. Anyway, if you trust your server and you want a simple implementation, I would suggest you to use a symmetric key

Comment: Can't I just generate a new private key when server starts and not store it anywhere (only keep it in memory)? This would mean that users would get logged out when server restarts (e.g. due to technical issues), but it still seems more secure than storing the key somewhere else.

Comment: Roman, that would work if you only have one auth server. If you have more than one auth server they need to share the key.